# Now to get a QUICK answer I need to enter into Chat or parent site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, chat

I am not sure Whether asking this question means a lot!

I have seen the http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/ and it looks absolutely awesome!!!. Great move by the community and applauds for the creators.

Now to discuss about a Topic or any question, Do I need to post it in parent site or in chat? If both are possible, how does it move forward if users start asking in chat then in parent site?

**OR**

Am I not clear about the Chat though I have read the [chat FAQ](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)? I have also read
"...so discussion should more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at Meta Stack Overflow — but in a chatty, interactive, **less strictly Q&A focused way**."

Comment: You might be interested in the answers to this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59892/use-cases-for-chat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generally only discuss **potential meta questions** on chat if...

1. you need more feedback before proceeding (you're trying to figure out if this is a dupe, if your question makes sense, what the historical precedent is, etc)
2. it's the type of question where you need dynamic, rapid back-and-forth, call-and-response type feedback. This also implies it's not "read my novella, kthx" almost by definition.

chat is more about overall community and interactive decisionmaking than specific Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

Questions belong on the main site.

So that the answers are available for:

1. posterity (someone else is likely to have the same problem sooner or later)
2. evaluation and rating by the community

---

**Aside:** If we start to see a lot of people asking questions on the chat, that represents an unanticipated downside, and some thought will have to go into how it is best handled.

Comment: an exceedingly unlikely outcome in practice, IMO, since you can't get rep from asking or answering anything on meta.